# Как запустить приложение в консоли pyhon с дальнейшей вставкой аргументов?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, exe, ос

Есть некоторое приложение, - допустим ConsoleApplication.exe. При его запуске оно предлагает ввести некоторое значение, а в ответ выводит что-то другое.

Необходимо чтобы все это выполняла программа в цикле, т.е чтобы программа сама запускала приложение, вставляла какую-то фразу, а результат записывала в какой-нибудь файл.

Пробовал запускать приложение через **os.system**, но не понятно как подставлять аргумент и имитировать возврат каретки.

Пример того что происходит в консоли при запуске приложения:

```
Введите ключ: //здесь_ввожу_ключ
какой_то_ответ
```

Как можно реализовать данный алгоритм?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для python есть специальный модуль – `subprocess`:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen('ConsoleApplication.exe', stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
p_stdout, p_stderr = p.communicate(input=b'112233')
print(p_stdout.decode())  # Выводим результат из консоли ConsoleApplication.exe
```

---

Еще пример:

Написал файл google_search.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import webbrowser

key = input('Search: ')
print('Search "{}"'.format(key))

webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://www.google.ru/search?q=' + key)
```

И вызываю, вызывается тот скрипт обрабатывает входные данные (`stdin`), выводит их (`stdout`) и открывает вкладку браузера по умолчанию:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen(['python', 'google_search.py'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
p_stdout, p_stderr = p.communicate(input='Котики в чашке'.encode())
print(p_stdout.decode())  # Search: Search "Котики в чашке"
```

Comment: А при чем здесь это? Мне программа выводит "Введите ключ", а задача python ввести этот ключ.

Comment: Неправильно понял вас, ну тогда надо подправить ответ

Comment: Это же уже сторонний процесс получается. Может ключ должен посылаться с помощью сигнала?